# On a class of functions on $(1;\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I am looking for examples of nonnegative functions $f:(1;\infty)\to [0;\infty)$ so that:

(i) $f$ is increasing, that is $x\leq y$ implies $f(x)\leq f(y)$.

(ii) $f(ab)\approx f(a)+af(b)$ for any $1\leq a,b< \infty$, that is there exists a constant $C>0$ so that $C^{-1} f(ab)\leq f(a)+af(b)\leq Cf(ab)$  for any $1\leq a,b< \infty$.

Here are some examples: positive constant, $f(x)=x$. If $f$ is satisfied so is $cf$, for any $c>0$.

My question is finding some other nontrivial examples of such functions?

Comment: Thanks AlexR, I mean $f(ab)\cong f(a)+af(b)$. Edited!

Comment: If f and g are in the class so is f+g (C is the max of the C values for f and g).